# Tomcat 9 getting BindException Address is already in use

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat

I installed `tomcat 9` and tried to run `tomcat9.exe` by double clicking it expected server to start, instead I saw that command prompt is just closing immediately without starting the server. I am using `jdk 1.8`, I tried few solution to solve this problem like changing

`call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%` to  `call "%EXECUTABLE%" run %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`   in `startup.bat`

and even I set `JAVA_HOME` in `catalina.bat`

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`

after above changes I tried to run `startup.bat` but I am getting below exception saying

```
09-Sep-2016 23:28:23.952 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize
end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

09-Sep-2016 23:06:31.634 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed
to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:944)
        ... 13 more

09-Sep-2016 23:28:25.006 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.
await: create[localhost:8005]:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

after this I changed port number in `server.xml` from `8080` to `9090`

```
  <Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

still I am getting same exception can anyone help me how to solve this problem.

I am unable to start the `tomcat server` by `tomcat9.exe` or `startup.bat`

Comment: Change port 8009 or turn off the service using it

Comment: Try to run it as an administrator.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb thanks for your reply which service do I need to turn off?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I changed port no `8009` and I am not getting first two exceptions but I am getting last exception `JVM_Bind`

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb  thank you very much I changes port numbers, `8009` and `8005` like you suggested, now I am able to run my `tomcat9` with port no `9090` by using `startup.bat`  thanks a lot.

Comment: Run netstat -abno  as admin in windows to see which processes using which ports. In you case some other processed used the same ports. May be tomcat was running as a service

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with the AJP connector on port 8009.

I'd leave the 8080 connector the way that it was.

Search for this line and change it:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```